# Get rootDir inside beforeSend function in Symfony to intercept Sentry event

Tags: symfony, sentry

I have a service who intercepts the events of Sentry. I'm using a function called beforeSend.

I would to load a json file who contains the data to scrub or to keep. It's a service and I build my constructor with a similar way than others, but the "$this" context doesn't exist when I'm in the debugger in this function.

The kernel is in the Global variables, but I think it's not a good idea... I only would to get the root dir and it's all, but I don't find how to do this in this class...  The constructor seems useless.

Someone could help me with a similar experience ?

***EDIT :***

**Service :**

```
namespace App\Services;

use Sentry\Event;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;

class SentryBeforeSendService
{
private static $rootDir;

public function __construct(KernelInterface $kernel)
{
    self::$rootDir = $kernel->getRootDir();
}

/**
 * Scrubs the value of all TARGET_PARAMETERS
 * in the event's request.
 *
 * @param Event $event
 *
 * @return Event
 */
public function beforeSend(Event $event)
{
    $rootDir = self::$rootDir;
    $event->setRequest(self::scrubRequest($event->getRequest(), $rootDir));
    try {
        $composerData = json_decode(file_get_contents($rootDir.'/../composer.json'), true);
        $version      = $composerData['version'];
        $event->setRelease($version);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        //do nothing
    }

    return $event;
}

/**
 * Scrubs GET and POST parameters
 *
 * @param array $request
 *
 * @return array
 */
private static function scrubRequest(array $request, $rootDir)
{
    // DO SOMETHING WITH $rootDir to scrub data with external file   
}}
```

**services.yml :**

```
 app.service.sentry_before_send:
     class: 'App\Services\SentryBeforeSendService'
     arguments: ['@kernel']
```

**config_prod.yml** :

```
sentry:
    dsn: "%sentry_dsn%"
    options:
        environment: "%sentry_environment%"
        # release: '%env(VERSION)%' #overridden from composer.json version in SentryBeforeSendService::beforeSend
        before_send: 'App\Services\SentryBeforeSendService::beforeSend'
```

But it seems the construct never happened.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you share some of the code you are using, such that others could reproduce the problem?

Comment: I edited my original post, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to inject a parameter, but I found a way to get the project_root from my method. Half victory ...

**config_prod.yml:**

```
sentry:
    dsn: "%sentry_dsn%"
    options:
        environment: "%sentry_environment%"
        # release: '%env(VERSION)%' #overridden from composer.json version in SentryBeforeSendService::beforeSend
        before_send: 'App\Services\SentryBeforeSendService::beforeSend'
        project_root: '%kernel.project_dir%'
```

**Service :**

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use Sentry\Event;
use Sentry\State\Hub;

class SentryBeforeSendService
{
private static $projectRoot;

/**
 * Scrubs the value of all TARGET_PARAMETERS
 * in the event's request.
 *
 * @param Event $event
 *
 * @return Event
 */
public function beforeSend(Event $event)
{
    $sentryClient      = Hub::getCurrent()->getClient();
    self::$projectRoot = $sentryClient->getOptions()->getProjectRoot();
    $event->setRequest(self::scrubRequest($event->getRequest()));
    try {
        $composerData = json_decode(file_get_contents(self::$projectRoot.'/composer.json'), true);
        $version      = $composerData['version'];
        $event->setRelease($version);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        //do nothing
    }

    return $event;
}}
```

Hope it'll help someone else.

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the `kernel.project_dir` parameter in your service constructor with a named parameter:

In your services.yml file:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        bind:
            string $kernelProjectDir: '%kernel.project_dir%'
```

Then in your service:

```
public function __construct(string $kernelProjectDir)
{
```

Comment: I edited the original post. I tried the injection of service on my service directly. But the constructor never seems to happen. Thank you for your answer.